# Python Simple Login: how can user generate random desired password and that password should be saved next to that username in text file?

Tags: python, random, firebase-authentication, passwords, exit-code

I am very new to programming, I am half way building my Simple Login based on the scenerio below.

Scenerio:
a client requires a simple login program with a menu of options

1. Login – for users who have previously registered. Username and password to be checked for validity.
2. Register – create a new user account.
3. Passwords – new users given the option to enter their own password or generate one.
4. **Generated passwords – user given the option to choose the password character types – numbers, symbols or letters. The default password length should be applied, but users should also be allowed to choose how many characters.**
5. Save file – usernames and passwords should be saved to a text file accounts.txt
6. **Exit – delay for 2 seconds before exit**
7. View accounts – to display user account information from the accounts.txt file (assuming that only admin have access to this program).

I am stuck at the part (Generated Passwords) how to shape that and i also dont know where to and how to add the part (Exit – delay for 2 seconds before exit) in my script please refer to image.
[part of code where I am stuck to let user generate random password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO8GU.jpg)
[part where user chooses to auto generate password while registerting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x1FP.jpg)

Comment: NEVER save a password; to a file ; at minimum hash it, better salt it before.

Comment: ok i will do that thank for the tip

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you need to add a delay of 2 seconds before the program exits.

You can do this using the time module.

```
import time
time.sleep(2) # pauses the program for two seconds
exit(0) # exits the program
```

Comment: ok cool, but should I def this in a function in my program and give user a choice if the the user wants exit?

Comment: This depends on you, you can directly add it to your program after you save the file containing usernames and passwords.